# Bash script - Printing every char in a new line

Tags: bash

My script should get a string and print every char(including space,!@#$ etc.) in a new line

The script works on standart input but fails when some of the special chars appears in the string

here's my script

```
#!/bin/bash
if (($#!=1)); then
    echo Please enter one string
    exit 0 
fi

 string="$1"
 num=`expr length $string`

 for (( i=1; i<=num; i++ )); do
 x=`expr substr $string $i 1`
 echo  "$x"
 done

exit 0
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 3):

To print each character in BASH you can do this without calling any external utility:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#string}; i++)); do
   echo "${string:i:1}"
done
```

Comment: Quote the variable: `"${string:i:1}"`, otherwise `*` will be expanded as a wildcard

Comment: Theres still wrong output when theres combination of $#@%
for "hi#$1"
the output is 
h
i
#

Comment: What is value of `$string` here?

Answer (score 1):

Always quote your variables unless you WANT word splitting and wildcard expansion:

```
num=$(expr length "$string")

x=$(expr substr "$string" "$i" 1)
```

Comment: Tnx 
but it still keeps failing whenever theres a space or "!" in the string

Comment: You also need quoting when you get the length. Like I said, ALWAYS quote.

Comment: Theres still wrong output when theres combination of $#@% for "hi#$1" the output is h i #

Comment: You need to type `scriptname 'hi#$1'` when you run the script, otherwise `$1` gets expanded in your shell command.